# How to retrieve data from another firebase project even it is not inlcuded in the project?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to retrieve data from another firebase project even it is not inlcuded in 
 same the project? is it possible?

Because the other app is in another project.

Answer (score 0):

Your could do like this

```
DatabaseReference other_db = FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance("https://my-project.firebaseio.com/nodeName")
            .getReference();
```